# java log4j INFO level problem

Tags: java, log4j

I am not sure what I could be doing wrong that causes info level messages not to appear.
Here is the situation

```
 class LogTest {
      protected final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass());
      ...
      public void start() {
            logger.error(logger.isInfoEnabled());
               logger.info("blah");
      }
      ...
  }
```

Logger is not referenced anywhere else in the class.

Here is the output:

```
 ERROR 2010-02-18 09:14:01,489 com.company.test.Test - true
```

I do not know what else to check in order to get info working.. according to the logger it is enabled.

Comment: can you post your log4j configuration? log4j.properties or log4j.xml?

Comment: how does you log4.properties file looks like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could have an appender that only acts on WARN or higher or you could have configured a filter.

Comment: INFO is likely being filtered out in whatever logging output you're looking at (console/file). You can also set the filter by package.

Comment: It was an appender, thanks.  +1 to Dolph also since I had not considered that possibility.

Answer (score 2):

Be sure that you have set the appropriate logging level. Additionally, [slf4j](http://www.slf4j.org/) and/with [logback](http://logback.qos.ch/) are the newer and preferred logging libraries.

You can change the logging level by doing the following: 

  `logger.setLevel(Level.INFO);`

Comment: The problem is **not** the log level of the logger, as shown by the output of the program.